# How to pass parameters from visualforce custom button url to apex controller in test class

Tags: apex

I have created a custom detail page button with below url. I am passing three para meters through vf page.

```
/apex/Vfpage?oliId={!Opportunity.Id}&customDate={!Opportunity.CustomDate__c}&Domain={!Opportunity.Domain__c}
```

I am passing id value in test class but not sure how to pass other para meters.

```
oppId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('oppId',opp.id);
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id',opp.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are doing it in the right way. Just continue putting needed parameters

```
PageReference myVfPage = Page.Vfpage;
Test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage);

Opportunity  opp = ... // create test opportunity with needed fields
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('oliId', opp.Id);
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('customDate', opp.CustomDate__c);
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Domain', opp.Domain__c);

ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(opp);
YourController controller = new YourController(sc);
```